# Upload a large number of objects to a Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I want to write a large number of objects to a Google Cloud Storage bucket. I am performing these writes in parallel in batches of 50 with a 1 second delay between writing each batch.

Here's my code.

```
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");

const keyFilename = "path/to/service/account/file";
const projectId = "projectId";
const googleCloudConfig = { projectId, keyFilename };
const storage = new Storage(googleCloudConfig);
const bucket = storage.bucket("bucketName");

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const writeDocs = async () => {
  try {
    const arr = new Array(1000).fill({ test: "test"});
    const promises = [];
    for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      const file = bucket.file(`test/${i}.json`);
      promises.push(file.save(JSON.stringify(arr[i]), () => console.log(`saved JSON document ${i} to storage`)));

      if (promises.length >= 50) {
        console.log("writing batch. total:", i+1)
        await Promise.all(promises);
        promises.length = 0;
        await sleep(1000);
      }
    }

    if (promises.length) {
      await Promise.all(promises);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

writeDocs();
```

I expect to have 1000 objects in the `test/` directory in my bucket at the end of this script but only have 400. Why is this? Are there any undocumented rate limits that are relevant here?

Comment: Are you sure all your objects meets criteria defined in the other properties?

Comment: Please don't duplicate questions on Stack Overflow.. You should actually wait for your other question to be re-opened since you edited it.